# "Vor wem scheuten sich die Kinder" or "Vor wen scheuten sich die Kinder"?

Tags: grammatical-case, pronoun

The answer key in my textbook says that the correct answer is the sentence with the dative wem but I don't understand why. Isn't scheuten (shied away) a movement requiring the accusative wen?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're taking the movement rule a bit too literally; as with many rules of grammar there are nuances and exceptions. I'd call *sich vor scheuen* a prepositional verb since the meaning with *vor* (to shy away) is somewhat different than the meaning without it (to avoid). The movement rule doesn't really apply with prepositional verbs and you kind of have to learn which case to use for each one. Dative is correct this time, see the sub-definition under def 1 in [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/scheuen#d-1-1-4) (the fourth chevron down).

Comment: Actually, I think the direction-vs.-location rule for *Wechselpräpositionen* could apply here as well. There are several similar usages of *vor*: *sich vor etw. fürchten/wegducken/gruseln*. In each case, *vor* is handled like a location (with dative), with a meaning much like the preposition *angesichts*. If *vor* was directional (with accustive), however, it would indicate a movement **towards** the complement---i.e. *to shy 'towards' sth.* (cf. *vor jmdn. treten; vor etw. ziehen*). That obviously wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus: Thanks. In general, the case with verb+*Wechselpräposition* type prepositional verbs isn't totally random and I assume there are many such patterns. I've noticed when there is no location at all then the accusative is often used, and if there is movement away then, as you said, the dative is often used. I suppose it comes down to whether you want to learn them one by one, or try to find patterns and then learn the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "scheuen" comes with accussative.

> Die Kinder scheuten jemanden(etwas)

This includes reflexive use, "sich scheuen".

But "vor" here needs the dative because "(sich) scheuen" is not a movement or direction.

> Die Kinder scheuten sich vor dem Käfig. Vor wem scheuten sie sich ?

https://www.dwds.de/wb/scheuen

https://www.dwds.de/wb/vor