# Meaning of "Der Pförtner passt auf sie auf"?

Tags: pronoun, separable-verb

Google Translate translates this as "The gatekeeper looks after them" but I don't understand how it got translated to that. What do the two "auf" mean in this sentence? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "Der Pförtner passt auf" means "The gatekeeper pays attention"

   aufpassen = pay attention
2. "Der Pförtner passt auf jemanden auf" means "The gatekeeper takes care of somebody / keeps an eye on somebody"

   auf jemanden aufpassen = keep an eye on somebody

In your sentence the word aufpassen is split into "passt auf jemanden auf" where the first auf points to the object on which the gatekeeper keeps an eye an the second auf belongs to aufpassen.

Comment: I suggest to add, that *aufpassen* is a separable  verb; this property causes, what you call *split*.

Answer (score 2):

The verb in the sentence is *aufpassen*. This yields the second *auf*. The first is a preposition.

Comment: *Pass auf dich auf,* is a common way of saying goodbye in German, equivalent to "Take care of yourself." Note, in reference to [this question from earlier today](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/65561/43989), *auf aufpassen* is another prepositional verb and the *auf* uses accusative even though there is no movement.