# Dative or Accusative after "auf."

Tags: preposition

"Er schaut auf den Baum." Why not "dem"? With "dem" would it mean that he is the tree?

Comment: With *dem* it would mean that he is *on* the tree.

Comment: No, he's not the tree himself but looking down from it. Depends on what you want to say, if you're looking at (auf den) or from (auf dem) the tree. A grammar text has the basics on dat. and acc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/65561/43989) since in involves a prepositional verb. There are several verbs that want you to specify a direction or a target of some kind, and the way to do that is with *auf* + accusative. These break the accusative=movement rule of thumb, but they have a mini-pattern of their own. Another example is *richten auf* + accusative -- "to point at (something)". RHa (who would know much better than I) is correct, *Er schaut auf dem Baum* would mean he is on the tree and looking from it; perhaps he went up there to get a better view.

Side note: When it comes to trees in general there is a subtle difference between *an* and *auf*; both translate into English as "on", though *auf* might be construed as "in" and *an* as "from". If something is physically attached then you'd normally use *an*: *Früchte hängen am Baum.* If something just happens to be there then you'd generally use *auf*: *Ich klettere auf den Baum.* If something isn't actually in/on the tree, but leaning against it, then you're back to *an*: *Der Mann lehnt am Baum.*

Comment: Auf/an might be easier to grasp when looking at situations where "auf" is simply not possible, like "die Schlüssel hängen *am* Haken"

Comment: These are all helpful answers (and exceedingly generous of you). Please tell me why Google gives "Er blickt auf ihr" but, in a story I am reading, I found "Sein Vater blickt auf ihn," which seems correct to me. Is Google wrong?

Comment: @Robyn El-Bardai: I can't be sure without knowing what you put into Google to get that result, but Google Translate is far from perfect. Also, *shauen* and *blicken* are different verbs and can mean different things. There probably is a plausible meaning for *Er blickt auf ihr,* but I don't know what if might be; I think *Er blickt auf sie* would be the normal phrase. Maybe there's another word? As in *Er blickt auf ihr Kleid.* It's really a different question and you might consider putting it in a separate post to get a better answer.